# ASN1 certificate parsing using openssl in OS-X

Tags: macos, parsing, code-signing, asn.1

I'd like to add my program a feature that can read specific fields from a given input certificate, which was acquired from LC_CODE_SIGNITURE inside the mach-o executable.

I'd like to start with the signer name, as i can easily check my work using the following command :

```
codesign -d --extract-certificates=/tmp/cert_note /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
```

This provided me a full list of certificate major fields in the following structure :

```
...
42:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE          
44:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :countryName
49:d=5  hl=2 l=   2 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :US
53:d=3  hl=2 l=  19 cons: SET               
55:d=4  hl=2 l=  17 cons: SEQUENCE          
57:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :organizationName
62:d=5  hl=2 l=  10 prim: UTF8STRING        :Apple Inc.
74:d=3  hl=2 l=  38 cons: SET               
76:d=4  hl=2 l=  36 cons: SEQUENCE          
78:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :organizationalUnitName
83:d=5  hl=2 l=  29 prim: UTF8STRING        :Apple Certification Authority
114:d=3  hl=2 l=  51 cons: SET               
116:d=4  hl=2 l=  49 cons: SEQUENCE          
118:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
123:d=5  hl=2 l=  42 prim: UTF8STRING        :Apple Code Signing Certification Authority
...
```

After some research, I was introduced to the following header /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h

does this API suitable for my needs ? can anyone give me code example for this specific case ?